# Save as table operation is failing when struct type element has fields with special character for SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below XML which I am trying to read through SPARK XML:

```xml
<revolt>
    <revolt_configuration>
        <id>102</id>
        <noncontroversial>
            <validation_method>SPARK</validation_method>
            <validation-timeout>5</validation-timeout>
        </noncontroversial>
    </revolt_configuration>
</revolt>
```

Please note field 'validation-timeout' under  noncontroversial

I am using below code to read the XML :

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').option('rowTag','revolt_configuration').load('data')
```

and printing the schema I get below output root

```
|-- id: long (nullable = true)
|-- testvalidationcontroller: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- validation-timeout: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- validation_method: string (nullable = true)
```

While trying to save this data frame to hive table, I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: : expected at the position 24 of 'bigint:struct<validation-timeout:bigint,validation_method:string>' but '-' is found.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.expect(TypeInfoUtils.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.expect(TypeInfoUtils.java:331)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.parseType(TypeInfoUtils.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.parseTypeInfos(TypeInfoUtils.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfosFromTypeString(TypeInfoUtils.java:765)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe.initialize(ParquetHiveSerDe.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.AbstractSerDe.initialize(AbstractSerDe.java:53)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(SerDeUtils.java:521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:391)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.checkValidity(Table.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:699)
        ... 44 more
```

Note that this issue is not related to XML as I faced the similar issue when reading JSON based data

If the struct field does not contain any special chars then save as table operation works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I further dig down into this issue and 
1. Seems like this issue originates from hive meta-store since when tried to execute query with sub-column containing special characters and despite adding backtick it did not work for me
2. I solved this issue by explicitly passing SQL expression to the data frame by updating special character from sub columns

Ex

```
source data :
{
  "address": {
    "lane-one": "mark street",
    "lane:two": "sub stree"
 }
}
```

Python CODE:

```
schema = 'struct<lane_one:string, lane_two:string>'
data_frame_from_json.select(col('address').cast(schema))
```

I have verified the data for much more complex JSON and XML structure and it looks good.